# Require some guidance on what to do with paint peeling from my wall

Tags: paint

just looking for some tips on how to deal with a slight issue i've run into with the paint on one of my walls.

Home background, it's an English house built in the late 70's pretty sure the actual walls haven't had a fresh coat of paint for a few decades we are in the process of renovating after purchasing the property and it was just multiple layers of wallpaper on the walls...

Anyway I got the wallpaper off this window wall and noticed the paint started peeling off I started scraping and a lot of it was coming off the wall almost like wallpaper, some of it came off easily while other parts felt more attached.

Peeling it off reveals the base wall plaster but the weird thing is that the backing of the paint feels like a rubbery material, should I scrape all of this from the plaster or only take off what comes easily and paint over it?

[image]

Comment: Given the popularity of "the damp" in the UK, and rare use of air conditioning (which dehumidifies), that might explain the paint failure.  Also, lead paint was almost phased out by the 1970s, so it's unlikely but I would check for that.  It's sweet-tasting, and if a child eats it, it will really mess up their brain.

Answer (score 1):

Is that wall plaster or concrete?  For the paint to peel off like that, something isn't right.  Either an oil type sealant was applied on that wall or lots of moisture is getting in that wall.

To check for moisture, you can get a moisture detector.
If moisture is not the issue, it means wrong paint was applied on a sealed surface.  Scrape off all the paint, use proper primer and then elastomeric paint.

Take care.

Comment: It's a plaster wall, I wet sponge the wallpaper from the wall and then started to clean the wall with some sugar soap water, would that be enough moisture to cause this

Comment: It seems to be under the window, might be a possibility that the window frame has a minor leak.